# Any .NET/Python Sample that create ADFV2 Custom activity for Azure Batch

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to look around for .NET or Python script that would creating ADFV2 Factory which runs Azure Batch Code.

Any links to this appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the Custom Activity document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity and Sample code here https://github.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory. Note that the sample code is for ADF V1 and Custom Activity has interface changed in V2. The sample code for V2 will be provided on GitHub soon later.